# Motivation for the Notion of Regular Function in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, motivation

I am studying algebraic geometry, and naturally came across the notion of regular functions as a way to make any algebraic variety a space with functions.

My problem with the notion of regular functions is that it seems arbitrary. Why study functions $f$, that are locally of the form $f=\frac{g}{h}\in \mathbb{C}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$? Is there any motivation for this from the geometric, algebraic, or historical viewpoint?

I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide concrete reasons -via examples or particular theorems- showing that your proposed motivation makes sense in the context of algebraic geometry.

Comment: I would strongly suspect that it arose in significant part from Several Complex Variables, in contrast to One Complex Variable, so that functions are no longer so simply locally representable as quotients $f(z)={g(z)\over (z-z_o)^n}$, but need a fancier denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the focus of the question, but you are studying *algebraic* geometry, not differential geometry, so it is natural to work with polynomials as functions on affine space. If you want the fraction field you get rational functions.  Were you expecting to be working with something that locally looks like $e^{-1/x^2}$ as a function?

If you work with varieties more complicated than affine or projective space then the ring of functions (or function field) can become more complicated than polynomials or rational functions, but the function field will consist of what classically would be called "algebraic functions" like $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, not something like $\sin x$.

Comment: The set of continuous functions $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is also a $K$-algebra, so there are other possibly interesting algebraic structures that could take the role of regular functions. Also, why study functions that are locally rational functions instead of just locally polynomials?

Comment: @SantiagoEstupiñán You should probably look into some of the specifics of the $\operatorname{Spec}$ functor. If you pass from affine $n$-space to an open set (Zariski or Euclidean), the set of polynomial functions defined on that open set is still $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Now (restricting our attention to Zariski open sets) if we look at rational functions, what we find is that the rational functions which are regular on the complement of $\left\{f=0\right\}$ are precisely those of the form "polynomial divided by a power of $f$." ...

Comment: ...So basically, we consider rational functions because they capture some of the geometry in a way that just looking at polynomials does not.

Comment: @SantiagoEstupiñán That $\operatorname{Hom}(U,K)$ can be made into a $K$-algebra doesn't mean much - a lot of things are algebras; being an algebra does not indicate that it is studied in algebra. Why locally rational instead of locally polynomials? Localize/take the quotient field!